# Missing elements while comprehensing with np.all and getting removed indexes

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, numpy

I have a data set with the size of (400,40). Some of the columns are completely zero. They are not necessary for the calculations (I need to ignore them), but they are needed to rewrite the file.

So I'm using numpy to import it as an array, get the initialization done. But a problem occurs when I try to inverse the matrix (again, needed for the calculations). As far as I know, if a matrix has a full zero column, it is impossible to inverse it (det(M) = 0).

So I am using this to get non-zero columns:

```
nonZero = dataSet[:, np.all(dataSet != 0, axis=0)]
```

(I also tried summing the column with np.sum within np.all) but it skips some columns for no reason.

For example, my first row has:

```
[ 0, -1, -2, -3, 181, 5451, 0, 0, 8, 8, 1, 9, 9, 1, 0.11, 0, 0 ] etc.
```

When I run the above code, I get:

```
[ -1.  -2.  -3.  181.  8.  8.  1.  9.  9.  1.  ]
```

5451 and 0.11 disappears even though the whole column does not equal 0 nor they are 0.

I also need to get the removed column indexes, since I need to rewite them after the calculations...

I am not the best Python coder, but I can't seem to fix the problem, or understand why it happens. I recently learned how to use numpy and I am pretty beginner in it. This has been troubling me for 2 days now. Any recommendation/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.all` is like `and` it will check every value if its zero. What you want is to use `np.any` for `or` like behaviour i.e. if you want to neglect the 0's present in the non-zero column example

```
dataSet = np.array([[ 0, -1, -2, -3, 181, 5451, 0, 0, 8, 8, 1, 9, 9, 1, 0.11, 0, 0 ],
                [ 0, -1, -2, -3, 181, 5451, 0, 0, 8, 8, 1, 9, 9, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
                [ 0, -1, -2, -3, 181, 0,    0, 0, 8, 8, 1, 9, 9, 1, 0.11, 0, 0 ]])
nonZero = dataSet[:, np.any(dataSet, axis=0)]
nonZero
```

```
array([[ -1.00000000e+00,  -2.00000000e+00,  -3.00000000e+00,
          1.81000000e+02,   5.45100000e+03,   8.00000000e+00,
          8.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   9.00000000e+00,
          9.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.10000000e-01],
       [ -1.00000000e+00,  -2.00000000e+00,  -3.00000000e+00,
          1.81000000e+02,   5.45100000e+03,   8.00000000e+00,
          8.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   9.00000000e+00,
          9.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
       [ -1.00000000e+00,  -2.00000000e+00,  -3.00000000e+00,
          1.81000000e+02,   0.00000000e+00,   8.00000000e+00,
          8.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   9.00000000e+00,
          9.00000000e+00,   1.00000000e+00,   1.10000000e-01]])
```

If you want to extract columns indicies you can use `np.where` i.e

```
np.where(~dataSet.any(axis=0))
```

Output:

```
(array([ 0,  6,  7, 15, 16]),)
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a mistake in your logic. You don't want to discard the columns where all values are **nonzero**. Given the explanation you want to discard columns that are all zero:

For example:

```
arr = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
                [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
arr[:, ~np.all(arr == 0, axis=0)]
# array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
#        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
#        [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

But you can also use [`np.any`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html) instead of `np.all`:

```
arr[:, np.any(arr != 0, axis=0)]
```

Comment: ah, I made a mistake in the question. Yes that was the true logic! Thanks for the recommendation but it did not work for me. Did not make any changes to the rows :\

Comment: oh, nevermind my logic is true but my code was wrong. Still it didn't work. I guess there's a problem with how I import the list...

Answer (score 1):

It's always best to work with smaller examples.

For instance:

```
arr = np.array([
    [0, 0, 1],
    [0, 1, 1]
])

nonzero = arr != 0
print(nonzero)
# prints
# [[False False  True]
#  [False  True  True]]

all_nonzero = np.all(nonzero, axis=0)
print(all_nonzero)
# prints
# [False False  True]
```

Now you see the problem. Your logic creates a column mask that only selects columns for which *all* elements in the column are non-zero. What you actually want are the columns where *not all the elements are zero*, or put another way: where *any* element in the column is non-zero.

```
any_nonzero = np.any(nonzero, axis=0)
print(any_nonzero)
# prints
# [False  True  True]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now I see the problem. Unfortunately I'm still learning about python and didn't know if we could debug with bools!